# Remove objects from array based on keys & properties in another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the following object, where the property key is set to a username and the property value is set to a count of the number of times they appear, and an array containing a list of objects with properties of `UserId`, and `UserName`:

```
peopleWhoAppear = { "Edward": 5, "Charlotte": 2, "Michael": 9, "Andy": 6 }

siteUsers = [ 
  { UserId: 1842, UserName: "Sam" }, 
  { UserId: 2943, UserName: "Charlotte" }, 
  { UserId: 1842, UserName: "Richard" },
  { UserId: 2916, UserName: "Ivan" },
  { UserId: 2073, UserName: "Paul" },
  { UserId: 1842, UserName: "Theo" }
  ...
]
```

I would like to remove all objects from the `siteUsers` array where the `UserName` matches a property key in the `peopleWhoAppear` object if the property value matches a certain number (it could be 5 or 8) and return the remaining results to another array. I've been stuck on this for 6 hours over 2 days now and I've not made any progress.

I've tried varies permutations and loops of `.filter` and `.splice`, but with no success. For example:

```
 for (var UserName in peopleWhoAppear) {
   if (peopleWhoAppear[UserName ] === count) {
                siteUsers.filter(function (person) {
                    console.log(person);
                    return person.UserName !== verifier;
                }));
     }
 }
```

How can I accomplish this? I don't have access to any libraries apart from jQuery so things like Underscore are not useful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've tried varies permutations and loops of `.filter` and `.splice`, but with no success.

You will only need `filter`:

```
return siteUsers.filter(function(obj) {
    var user = obj.UserName;
    return !(user in peopleWhoAppear && peopleWhoAppear[user] == count);
});
```

This will get you a new array, with all the users that did not appear in `peoplWhoAppear` or had the wrong count in there.

Answer (score 2):

`Filter()` doesn't change the array, it returns a new one. If you want to iteratively filter the array, you have to set it to the return value of `filter()` each time.

```
// copy the array
var newSiteUsers = siteUsers.slice(0)  

for (var UserName in peopleWhoAppear) {
   if (peopleWhoAppear[UserName ] === count) {
                newSiteUsers = newSiteUsers.filter(function (person) {
                    console.log(person);
                    return person.UserName !== UserName;
                }));
     }
 }

console.log(newSiteUsers);
```