# Javascript Remove Item from array 1 if value exists in array 2

Tags: javascript, arrays

Array 1

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Test" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Test2" } ]
```

Array 2

```
[ { "id": 1, "name": "Test3" }, { "id": 2, "name": "Test4" }, { "id": 3, "name": "Test2" } ]
```

If item exists in Array 2, I need to remove it from Array 1, so Test2 would be removed from Array 1. How can I loop through both arrays and check the name value's presence in Array 2 in order to remove it from Array 1?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about this? Why is the element with ID `1` not removed?

Comment: So, you are comparing by `name`, not `id`?

Comment: You should be able to use [`array_filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for this.

Comment: Convert Array 2 to an object that uses the IDs as property names. Then loop through Array 1, removing the elements that can't be found in the object.

Comment: @RocketHazmat That's PHP. You mean `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: When testing if it exists, do you have to check body `id` and `name`, or just one of them?

Comment: @Barmar just checking name

Comment: So make an object whose properties are the names from Array 2. Then filter Array 1 based on whether element.name is in the object.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075531/remove-objects-from-array-based-on-keys-properties-in-another-object for how to do the second part.

Comment: @Barmar: Whoops, wrong language.  My bad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org) for this kind of thing...

```
array1 = _.reject(array1, function(e1) {
    return _.find(array2, function(e2) { return e1.name == e2.name });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var existingIds = array2.map(function (item) { // create a list of existing ids in array 2
        return item.id;
    });

var filteredArray = array1.filter(function (item) { // check each item against existingIds, and if not found there return it
        return existingIds.indexOf(item.id) === -1;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without doing an O(n^2) search, we can do it looping once on each array, with a little extra memory overhead.

```
var map = new Map();
array2.forEach(function(item) {
    map.set(item.name, true);
});
var result = array1.filter(function(item) {
    return !map.has(item.name);
});
```

Note: I used Map simply because it has additional features, such as setting keys based on any value.  A simple object can be used.